Spring application exclude class from Maven dependency
I have a project that uses a custom dependency (xl.person.controller.PersonController) of which I overwrite a PersonController class. It is a multi module project.
The PersonController class is inside the external module (this module also has the dependency) - @RestController annotations
In my Application module, I instantiate the beans as such and I would expect the PersonController from the custom dependency not to be included. As you can see, the componentScan is needed for other classes I do use from the custom dependency
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = "xl.person",
    excludeFilters={
        @ComponentScan.Filter(
            type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
            value = { xl.person.controller.PersonController.class }
        )
    }
)
public class PersonConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    PersonController personController(
        PersonService service, //from dependency
        PersonSecondService serviceTwo //not from dependency
    ) {
        return new PersonController(service, serviceTwo);
    }
}

I also tried the exclude on the @SpringBootApplication approach
@SpringBootApplication(
    scanBasePackages = "xl.app"
    exclude = { PersonController.class }
)


Annotation-specified bean name 'personController' for bean class [xl.person.controller.PersonController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [xl.app.external.PersonController]

Update
Trigger seems to be the @RestController on the PersonController definition I have. So in the external Module the class is already created and then conflict with the custom dependency. However I do want to keep the @RestController on my Controller class for obvious reasons.
Also the @ComponentScan on my configuration class seems to be ignored (hence not working) because @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="xl.app") does the first scan I think and already throws the error. However and exclude = { PersonController.class } of the custom dependency class does not work here.

Do you, maybe, have other configuration classes that might scan for that package?

@MarioMateaș I assume you mean the @ComponentScan? No. I DO have in my @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="xl.app") where the module External also falls under, but this should not interfere.

@SpringBootApplication is a "convenience" annotation and can be replaced with something like:
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "xl.person", excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(
            type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
            value = { xl.person.controller.PersonController.class }
        )
})

This resolved the conflict error you mentioned in your question for me.
It is fairly easy to reproduce that error for testing, e.g. just place the following class in two different packages:
package xl.person.controller; // add .alt for second location

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PersonController {

    public int getSize() {
        return 1;
    }
    
}

and start the application with, for example, mvn spring-boot:run
On a side-note: the exclude property in @SpringBootApplication is only for auto-configuration classes and has no effect on regular components/beans.
